# Repeat a replace in n lines for multiple files in notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++, text-editor

I have a bunch of files with 18 lines of text as header. I wish to comment those lines, which I normally do with the regular expression replacer searching ^ and replacing by # on the selected 18 lines. 
I must do the very same on all files (sometimes more than 50), so it would be very useful to be able to do the "replace in all documents" only between rows 1 to 18 for example, or replace only in text lines.

I've tried also the macro recording, but in any case I must select the desired lines.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible with Npp. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Ok as a quick fix I wrote a linux command to do this, but is sad that something so simple cannot be done in npp.
`for i in *; do awk 'NR==1,NR==18 { print "#" $0; next } { print }'; done`